# minio docker runs in Ubuntu (VirtualBox), trying to connect to minio server from host machine (MacOS or Win10), connection reset

Tags: docker, ubuntu, amazon-s3, virtualbox, minio

**The Context:**

- Got minio (s3 compatible storage) from docker hub
- Run the minio docker image in Unbuntu (VirtualBox)
- Host OS: Mac or Win10
- Set up network -> port forwarding -> 9000:9000 in VirtualBox

**The Problem:**
- In Ubuntu, minio works perfectly, http://localhost:9000
- Outside Ubuntu, in Win10 or Mac (host), any client failed to connect to the minio server. Error: connection reset.

**Alternative Test:**
- Installed and run minio directly in host machine
- Connection from any client was successful

**The Question:**
- Why did I connect to minio server in Ubuntu (VirtualBox) failed from host machine? What was the root cause?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Go to VirtualBox, select the Ubuntu image, go to Networks tab and select "Attached to" as "Bridged Adapter". This will bring the Ubuntu machine on the same network as the host's. Now restart Ubuntu, type

`sudo ifcongif`

and see the IP address that Ubuntu has received.

Now, from the host machine, go to http://IP:9000 and you should be able to access your container.

Comment: Hi 7_R3X, thanks, I used NAT - Port Forwarding in network, just modified my post to include the info, I forgot to mention at first place. Sorry. My question is why NAT-port forwarding won't work? The NAT port forwarding works for my other servers in Ubuntu, but not for minio. It also happened to other S3 compatible docker, like s3server. I started wondering: Does it have something to do with s3 protocol?

Comment: @MichaelQin: I'm not aware of s3 protocol. Does it create its own VPN and works on top of it? That could be the reason why it wouldn't work. Not sure though.